# Populating field based on selecting picklist value using LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

My requirement is I need to populate a field based on selected picklist field value in LWC

HTML

```html
<template>
    <lightning-card>
        <p class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">
            <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="AVTRRT__Job__c">
                <lightning-input-field field-name="Business_Unit__c" onchange={projectChange}>
                </lightning-input-field>
            </lightning-record-edit-form>
            <select class="slds-select" >
                <option value="Select">Select</option>
                <template for:each={options} for:item="option">
                    <option key={option.label} class="uiInputSelectOption" value={option.value}>{option.value}</option>
                </template>
            </select>
        </p>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

JS

```javascript
import { LightningElement , wire, track} from 'lwc';
import getUnit from '@salesforce/apex/JobFetch.getUnit';
export default class PriceScreen extends LightningElement {
@track options;
projSelected;
projectChange(event) {
    console.log('hhh');
    console.log('gg33gg' + event.detail.value);
    this.projSelected = event.detail.value;
    getUnit({ projId:this.projSelected })
        .then(result => {
            this.options = result.map((record)=>({label: record.Name, value: record.Id}));
        })
       .catch(error => {
           this.options = undefined;
       });
    }
}
```

APEX

```apex
public with sharing class JobFetch {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    public static List<String> getUnit(String projId) {
        List<String> joblst = new List<String>();
        List<Position__c>  poslst = [Select Id, Name from Position__c where Business_Unit_Name__c  =:projId];
        List<String> posname = new List<String>();
        if(!poslst.isEmpty()){
            for(Position__c pos: poslst)
            posname.add(pos.Name);
        }
        return posname;
    }
}
```

But on select of Business Unit picklist, I am not getting anything in 'Select' picklist.

Please help me on this

Result I am getting is: data is there, but not visible

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't actually map the values as `[ { label: something, value: somethingElse }, ... ]`, as your template expects. You can map the data to match:

```
getUnit({ projId:this.projSelected })
   .then(result => {
    this.options = result.map((option)=>({label: option, value: option}));
   })
```

Personally, I'd map both the ID and Name as value/label in case you have duplicates:

```
@AuraEnabled 
public static List<Position__c> getUnit(String projId) {
  return [Select Id, Name from Position__c where Business_Unit_Name__c  =:projId];
}
```

...

```
getUnit({ projId:this.projSelected })
   .then(result => {
    this.options = result.map((record)=>({label: record.Name, value: record.Id}));
   })
```

Comment: Hi sfxfox..thanks for you reply..i edited my code based on your comment.Please check my updated code  But now the data is not visible.it is populating but not visible

Comment: @YogeshSakatAphidas Did you change the Apex to match? Either use the first code block without changing the Apex, or change both the Apex (second block) and the JavaScript (third block) to match.

Comment: I used the first block without changing the apex. Tried the second block..it is working..thanks

Comment: @YogeshSakatAphidas Great! I'm happy I could help.